# Mysql order by campo data valor original

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo uma query e estou transformando a `data no formato` brasileiro e depois quero usar a `data_vencimento` original no `order by` mas não funciona

código:

```
SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(data_vencimento,'%d/%m/%Y') as data_vencimento, DATE_FORMAT(data_pagamento,'%d/%m/%Y') as data_pagamento FROM cta_pagar WHERE id_nota='$nota' AND id_fornecedor='$fornecedor' ORDER BY data_vencimento ASC
```

Eu sei porque não funciona, estou fazendo uma variável `data_vencimento` com o mesmo nome do campo mas eu preciso fazer isso para evitar complicações no jquery.

O que eu peço que vocês me ajudem é como fazer para quando eu dar o `ORDER BY data_vencimento ASC` ele usar o valor original do campo ao invés da data formatada(string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que qualificando o campo funcione, não tenho Mysql e não tenho como testar

```
SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(DATA_VENCIMENTO,'%d/%m/%Y') AS DATA_VENCIMENTO,     DATE_FORMAT(DATA_PAGAMENTO,'%d/%m/%Y') AS DATA_PAGAMENTO 
FROM CTA_PAGAR 
WHERE ID_NOTA='$nota' 
AND ID_FORNECEDOR='$fornecedor' 
ORDER BY CTA_PAGAR.DATA_VENCIMENTO ASC
```

Comment: Sim amigo é isso mesmo deu certo, Valeu.